# Entity Framework auto generate database to SQL Server Compact

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce-4

I am using VS 2012 and the model first approach in Entity Framework 6 to generate a database in SQL Server Compact 4.0. I have installed the Entity Framework package from NuGet and have added `EntityFramework.SqlServer.Compact` to my references. Once I build my model I try to generate the database with the "Generate database from model..." instruction. I can go through the Generate Database Wizard without any problems.

When I run  `update-database` in the Package Manger Console I get

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly

Fixing this error I used `Enable-Migrations` which gave me a new error

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel.

The connection string that was generated is below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1Container" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Users\RSargent\Desktop\CompactDatabase\MyDatabase1.sdf&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have tried using `|DataDirectory|` for the connection string path but this doesn't work for me as all I get is a few errors:

> Missing required whitespace

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1Container"
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase1.sdf""
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

From the research I have done usually the connection string is the problem in these situations. Am I setting up the connection string correctly? Or does anyone know of another reason why I can't auto-generate a database?